# Min Value Oracle with results of subqueries

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm struggling a little bit with syntax.

I'm trying to have the following line of code, with the upper boundary determined by a hard value and a sub-query or two sub-queries, picking the minimum value of the result.

```
AND ELIGTY_MO_YYYYMM BETWEEN '201407' AND '201412'
```

with the intended change being:

```
AND ELIGTY_MO_YYYYMM BETWEEN '201407' AND min('201412', select max(contract boundary) from table blah)
```

or replacing the `'201412'` with another sub-query.

I'm hoping this is a simple question.  Any insights would be greatly appreciated =)

Comment: Are you getting any syntax error (or) is not working?

Comment: It's giving an invalid number of arguments error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things...

1. When comparing two values, use `LEAST` and `GREATEST`. `MIN` and `MAX` are for aggregating only.
2. When using a subquery as a value in a column or expression, enclose the subquery in parentheses.

   ```
   AND ELIGTY_MO_YYYYMM BETWEEN '201407' AND
   LEAST('201412, (SELECT MAX(whatever) FROM table))
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are looking to use `least` instead.  Very generic example:

```
select *
from yourtable
where someval between 0 and 
    least((select min(someval) from yourtable), (select max(someval) from yourtable))
```

- [Condensed Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/76c62/5)

Answer (score 0):

You can write your second where clause in multiple forms:

as `fld< min(val1 , val2)` means `fld< val1 and fld< val2` then you can say:

```
AND ELIGTY_MO_YYYYMM >=201407 
    AND ELIGTY_MO_YYYYMM<= 201412
    AND ELIGTY_MO_YYYYMM<= (select max(contract_boundary) from table)
```

or you can use a `case` statement:

```
AND ELIGTY_MO_YYYYMM >=201407 
    AND ELIGTY_MO_YYYYMM <= (
        select max( case 
                       when contract_boundary<201412 then 201412 
                       else contract_boundary end)
        from table)
```

or use `least`:

```
AND ELIGTY_MO_YYYYMM BETWEEN 201407 AND
LEAST(201412, (SELECT MAX(whatever) FROM table))
```